# How to design nested loop if the limit is not multiple of parent and child limits, without using break

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a code like below;

```
let total = 15;
let batch = 5;
let batchRuns = 3;

for (let i = 0; i < batchRuns; i++) {
    for(let j=0;j<batch;j++){
        console.log("hello");
    }
    console.log("-------------");
}
```

Now, this will print `hello` 15 times since 5x3=15. What if I want to print `hello` 14 times or 13 times, by keeping batch like 5+5+4 or 5+5+3. What I mean is, I want to print dashes after every 5 `hello`s and in the last iteration if it is below 5, I want to print line after that as well.

let me show the expected outputs

**Case 1**

```
total = 10;

hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
-------------
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
-------------
```

**Case 2**

```
total = 12;

hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
-------------
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
-------------
hello
hello
-------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last `batchRuns`, calculate the `batch` and add dashes to output.

```js
let total = 12;
let batch = 5;
let batchRuns = 3;

for (let i = 0; i < batchRuns; i++) {
  let currentBatch = i == batchRuns - 1 ? total % batch : batch;
  for (let j = 0; j < currentBatch; j++) {
    console.log("hello");
  }
  console.log("-------------");
}
```